# Issue accessing AWS EMR Dask cluster Bokeh dashboard via Chrome

Tags: bokeh, dask, amazon-emr

I am trying to access the Dask Bokeh dashboard on an AWS EMR cluster via Chrome, but nothing is shown when I click on the linked dashboard.

I set-up the cluster using this [workflow](https://yarn.dask.org/en/latest/aws-emr.html). When I click on the linked dashboard, I see nothing unless I click on "Info" where I can only find information on the workers.

What am I missing to see the entire Dask Bokeh dashboard?

Comment: This may be a tornado 6 incompatibility issue with jupyter-server-proxy (https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyter-server-proxy/issues/115). Try adding `tornado=5` to the conda install command in the bootstrap action (https://github.com/dask/dask-yarn/blob/a991a88cf3d82106c16391b7e1ed6148a67be4ca/deployment_resources/aws-emr/bootstrap-dask#L105-L116). If that fixes it, can you file a PR https://github.com/dask/dask-yarn/pulls to add that requirement to the bootstrap action?

Comment: @jiminy_crist There's no tornado in the example boostrap: https://github.com/dask/dask-yarn/blob/master/deployment_resources/aws-emr/bootstrap-dask

Comment: @jiminy_crist I used `tornado==5` and no result.

Comment: Can you file an issue in the dask-yarn repo please https://github.com/dask/dask-yarn/issues